# Visual Studio Community 2013 Uninstall - This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Trying to uninstall Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 5 i got the following error, Setup Failed:

> Setup Engine
>   This operation returned because the timeout period expired

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, restarted the uninstall process and was then met with the standard UAC dialog.

> User Account Control 
>   Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer

Answer yes and the program could be uninstalled successfully.